# Creating case sensitive catalog

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to create multiple rows having the same value but different case to a table with a Primary Key defined on a string column.

By default SQL server wouldn't allow you to do that, is there a way I can tell SQL server this is permitted?

Answer (score 2):

By changing ‘Database Collation’ parameter we can control the database case sensitivity.

The default collation is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS (CI => Case-insensitive)

By changing to  SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS (CS => Case sensitive) you can enable 2 rows having same primary key with different case.

Comment: Additionally, you can set the collation on the column as well as at the DB level.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the COLLATION of the column on your table to be case sensitive.
First figure out what collation your database is using.

```
SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX(DB_NAME(), 'Collation') AS CollationUsedBySQLServerDatabase
-- Mine was Finnish_Swedish_CI_AS
```

Pick the same one for your table, but choose it to be case sensitive (Finnish_Swedish_CS_AS)

```
create table Users
(
    UserName varchar(5000) COLLATE Finnish_Swedish_CS_AS PRIMARY KEY 
)

insert Users(UserName)
Values ('Peter'), ('PETER')

select * from Users
```